# firebase Realtime database paging with query

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Firedatabase with Unity3d.
My Issue is the user search for data, and I retrieve only 50 result each time,
It is easy to get first 50 record

```
Database.RootReference.Child("ID").OrderByChild(AppSettings.UserFullNameKeyLowCase).StartAt(_search.ToLower()).LimitToLast(50);
```

The problem is getting the next 50 requires to have multiple StartAt, which firebase dose not support.

I did a lot of research and it seems its impossible to do that in a direct way.

My question Is there any way to do that, any alternative or third party tool to do that,

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get 50 entries at a time from a specific entry?
You could use your own code to get the first 50 results; record the last one and use that variable as the StartAt parameter for the next search.
You could use for loops to download the next 50 data each time.